# how to typecast the URL in String in android?

Tags: android

when typecast the URL in String in android the not getting the response...error occur in typecasting.

```
 public String abc(String url)
    {
        {
            try
            {
                URL a = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)a.openConnection();
                http.setRequestMethod("get");
                int res = http.getResponseCode();
                String s = String.valueOf(res);
                Log.i("", s);
            }   

            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: what's exactly your issue ?

Comment: have you tried googling? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get` should be `GET`

```
http.setRequestMethod("GET");
int response = http.getResponseCode();
Log.i("response", Integer.toString(response));
```

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29)